# Why does LocalDate with custom DateTimeFormatter pattern incorrectly set the time with zone?

Tags: java, java-11, java-time

Given the following test I would have expected the time to be the same, but it's not.

```
@Test
public void canGetCorrectOffsetFromFormatterDateParse()  {

    Instant isoDateInstant = LocalDate.parse("2009-12-31",
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toInstant();
    System.out.println(isoDateInstant);
    assertThat(isoDateInstant).isEqualTo("2009-12-31T05:00:00Z");

    Instant customDateInstant = LocalDate.parse("03-31-2020",
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu")
                    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT))
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toInstant();
    System.out.println(customDateInstant);
    assertThat(customDateInstant).isEqualTo("2020-03-31T05:00:00Z");

}
```

This test fails with the assertion of the customeDateInstance

```
Expected :2020-03-31T05:00:00Z
Actual   :2020-03-31T04:00:00Z
```

Q: Why are the times that are being appended not the same, and how do I standardize the time portion going forward?

These tests were run in VA, USA, which is the America/New_York ZoneId.

Comment: @sp00m Was just thinking the same thing..remove the lines of code that distract. The test  could also be refactored, do you want me to do that too?

Comment: I suggest adding the timezone into the test itself to actually make it easily reproducable.

Comment: NewYork in March is UTC-4.

Comment: Also you assert that an `Instant` is equal to a `String`, which it never will be!

Comment: @JoachimSauer AssertJ has overloads to handle that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), `America/New_York` is GMT-5 in "winter" and GMT-4 in "summer".

In 2020:

- "winter" to "summer" was on Sunday, March 8, 2:00 am,
- "summer" to "winter" was on Sunday, November 1, 2:00 am.

As expected, your code then:

- gives `2020-03-05T05:00:00Z` with `03-05-2020` ("winter"),
- gives `2020-03-15T04:00:00Z` with `03-15-2020` ("summer").